# java, typescript base angular project parser.js error

Tags: typescript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using java based angular2 project.

using following maven plugin with `sonarcube version 6.7.1`

```
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603
```

i have added exclusiosn for .js and .js.map files as following.

```
<sonar.excludes>**/*.js,**/js.map,**/node_modules</sonar.excludes>
```

when i run my project i can see these files in log has marked as exclusions.

in log i see following ERROR followed by build success

```
    [INFO] Sensor TypeScript Sensor [typescript]
[ERROR] /Users/user1/abc/web/target/sonar/sonarts-bundle/node_modules/tslint-sonarts/lib/utils/parser.js:30
[ERROR] function parseString(source, scriptKind = ts.ScriptKind.TSX) {
[ERROR]                                         ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
[ERROR]     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
[ERROR]     at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
[ERROR]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
[ERROR]     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
[ERROR]     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
[ERROR]     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
[ERROR]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user1/abc/web/target/sonar/sonarts-bundle/node_modules/tslint-sonarts/lib/runner/tsrunner.js:24:18)
[ERROR]     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
[ERROR]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
[ERROR] External process `node /Users/user1/abc/web/target/sonar/sonarts-bundle/node_modules/tslint-sonarts/bin/tsrunner` returned an empty output. Run with -X for more information
```

even though build success but still wana know why i am getting this error.

Comment: Is this the complete SyntaxError stacktrace?

Comment: Java != JavaScript.  They are completely different languages.

Comment: what is the version of NodeJS you have installed?

Comment: @ Tibor Blenessy my nodejs version is 4.5.0

Comment: @Amy yes i know that

Comment: @Jeroen Heier i have added the full stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have some TypeScript files which you didn't exclude. Their presence launches TypeScript sensor which requires Nodejs >=6.

So you should either exclude TypeScript files as well or update your Node

Comment: i upgraded nodejs to 9.5.0 and fixed the problem